# Multiple JAR export errors

Tags: java, jar, export

Don't know why, I can't export Eclipse project to JAR.
[Results of exporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm4Z9.png)
My java code, in case that is the problem:

```
package com.binbanner;

import java.util.List;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.BannerMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class BannerCheckPlugin
  extends JavaPlugin
  implements Listener, CommandExecutor {

  private boolean running = true;

  @Override
  public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    getCommand("sm").setExecutor(this);
    getCommand("stm").setExecutor(this);
    getLogger().info("BinBanner private plugin enabled");
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("BinBanner private plugin system closed");
  }
  private boolean hasRequiredPatterns(BannerMeta bannerMeta) {
        // Check lore for each required pattern
        List<String> lore = bannerMeta.getLore();
        return (
          lore != null &&
          lore.contains("White Roundel") &&
          lore.contains("Black Cross") &&
          lore.contains("Red Chief") &&
          lore.contains("Red Base") &&
          lore.contains("Red Bordure")
        );
      }
  @EventHandler
  public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
    if (!(event.getWhoClicked() instanceof Player)) {
      return; // Ignore non-player inventories
    }

    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
    if (!running) {
      player.sendMessage("Command ignored. BinBanner is not running.");
      return;
    }

    ItemStack clickedItem = event.getCurrentItem();
    if (clickedItem != null && clickedItem.getType() == Material.BANNER) {
      BannerMeta bannerMeta = (BannerMeta) clickedItem.getItemMeta();

      if (bannerMeta != null && hasRequiredPatterns(bannerMeta)) {
        // Remove the banner from the inventory
        player.getInventory().remove(clickedItem);
      }
    }
  }



  private void startPlugin(Player player) {
    if (!running) {
      running = true;
      player.sendMessage("Done! BinBanner started.");
    } else {
      player.sendMessage("Command ignored. BinBanner is already running.");
    }
  }

  private void stopPlugin(Player player) {
    if (running) {
      running = false;
      player.sendMessage("Done! BinBanner in hibernation.");
    } else {
      player.sendMessage(
        "Command ignored. BinBanner is already in hibernation."
      );
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCommand(
    CommandSender sender,
    Command command,
    String label,
    String[] args
  ) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)&& running == true) {
      sender.sendMessage("Unable to use command: Entity type is incorrect");
      return true;
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if (!player.isOp()) {
      player.sendMessage("Command unable to run: Insufficient permissions");
      return true;
    }

    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("sm")&& running == true) {
      startPlugin(player);
    } else if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("stm")&& running == true) {
      stopPlugin(player);
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

I don't think it is the java code causing the problem, I think it could be the build path which I didn't fix correctly. I am trying to do this in Eclipse, but if there is a way to export it using the same files from Eclipse in a different way, that might solve the problem. What I've noticed is that using javac also doesn't work, for some reason it asks me to select an app to open javac.

Tried fixing the Build Path, didn't work. Keeps saying the same thing. What actually happened, was it created a JAR, but appears to not be the full JAR.

Comment: I don't use this IDE but I would guess that ensuring all dependent jars are within the project's library directory would help

Comment: Dependent jars as in the import statements? Besides that it doesn't need anything